# Data Frame Header Error - not as many columns as expected

Tags: python, dataframe, header

I've been working on a little python script to sort some data from a .txt file into a bit better organised .csv file. 
However, pandas is not recognizing the header im giving the df. Maybe its because i need some more headers which doesn't exist so far in the file.

Here is some code so far:

```
df_csv = pd.read_csv(sort_file_path, delimiter = ',', headers = 3, names = ["Block:Ref","McFeeder","Package","ImgQuality","Thickness_Nominal(mm)","Thickness_Delta(mm)","Text","Winner_Model","Error_Bits","Angle(dg)","dX(mm)","dY(mm)","dTheta(dg)","ErrCode","3D_Test","Tilt(mm)","Measure","Measure2","Measure3","Measure4","Measure5","Measure6","Measure7",])
```

and now the file with the data with the headers : [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DObm.png)

and the error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rYOS.png)

I've tried several different things so far. Like name the headers separately or just without headers and let CSV do it.

This is the output I am expecting: [HowItShouldLook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Adz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to read it with:

```
sep = ';'
```

instead of

```
delimiter = ','
```

and without providing the headers?

It's better to provide all the data not as image but as a readable file

Comment: thanks for the fast answer!I will replace asap the pictures with files, i tried your solution but i ended up in noticing that no sep either delimiter is good here. It works better without any of that. But it is still saying my columns are to many : [